# Second Angular directive suffers from $timeout in first

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, timeout

When building a simple Angular App, i make use of two directives.
The first Directive creates a slideshow, the second services some readmore links.

```
app.directive('slider', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            images: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var timer;
            scope.currentIndex = 0; // Initially the index is at the first image

            scope.next = function() {
                scope.currentIndex < scope.images.length - 1 ? scope.currentIndex++ : scope.currentIndex = 0;
            };
            scope.prev = function() {
                scope.currentIndex > 0 ? scope.currentIndex-- : scope.currentIndex = scope.images.length - 1;
            };

            var sliderFunc = function() {
                timer = $timeout(function() {
                    scope.next();
                    timer = $timeout(sliderFunc, 5000);
                }, 10);
            };

            sliderFunc();

            scope.$watch('currentIndex', function() {
                scope.images.forEach(function(image) {
                    image.visible = false; // make every image invisible
                });

                if (scope.images.length > 0) {
                    scope.images[scope.currentIndex].visible = true; // make the current image visible
                }
            });

            scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                $timeout.cancel(timer); // when the scope is getting destroyed, cancel the timer
            });
        },
        templateUrl: 'app/slider.tpl.html'
    };
})
.directive('readMore', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.more = false;

            elem.find('.readmore').bind('click', function() {
                scope.more = scope.more === false ? true : false;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Both directives works as expected.

The first Directive uses a $timeout so the slideshow images cycle every 5 seconds.

Th problem exists in the readmore links.
When i click a link, the script (directive) waits for (max.) 5 sec. to execute, at the same moment the slide also executes.

I'm fairly new to Angular, but i thought directives, with the different scopes wouldn't interfere with each other.

What can i do so my readmore links wil trigger instantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because in the second directive, you are updating your scope in a jQuery click event, which is out out Angular life cycle.

The view will be then refreshed on the next digest cycle, which for instance is triggered by any `$timeout` call.

A quick and dirty fix is to call `scope.$apply()` (or `scope.$digest()`) in your click listener on the second directive.

A better fix would be to use the `ng-click` directive rather than a jQuery listener to catch click event the angular way (and then have them part of its life cycle - no need to manually $apply)

**update:** Here is how to use `ng-click`:

```
<a class="readmore" ng-click="more = !more">Read more</a>
```

---

As a side note, you should probably use `$interval` instead of `$timeout` as it is what you actually simulate.

Comment: Thanks for the `$interval` tip, this feels much better.

Comment: I tried using `ng-click` in stead of the jQuery listener, but i still lack the skills to make it work.

The html anchor is not the same element as the directive is called on.
`ng-click` doesn't seem to work there.

`<div class="text" read-more>
 <h3>Title</h3>
 <p class="less" ng-hide="more">Lorum ipsum.</p>
 <p class="more" ng-show="more">Lorum ipsum long...</p>
 <a class="readmore" ng-click="readmore">Read more</a>
</div>`

Comment: You need to pass an expression to `ng-click`, such as `ng-click="readmore()"` (note the parenthesis). Then in `$scope.readmore` you would put a function that do the job.

Comment: Or without function you can directly put all the logic: `ng-click="more = !more"` (the `!` will toggle the boolean value, true is false and false is true). I have updated my answer with this example. That would be way cleaner to do it this way, please keep trying until it works, we can help you.

Comment: Glad it works. The main idea to remember is that using jQuery is never a good idea, that why it's not included in Angular by default: always try to do things the angular way and you will avoid many problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying scope.more out of the angular context. Please invoke scope.$digest() there

```
  elem.find('.readmore').bind('click', function() {
            scope.more = scope.more === false ? true : false;
            scope.$digest();
        });
```